# Getting around closure when assigning Events to objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, events, closures, dom-events

**What I want to accomplish:**
I have an array of objects that each have a reference to a DOM node, that I call with `.getNode()`. I am trying to assign an event handler to each of these objects in the array, so that when clicked, `alert()` calls `.name` for the given object in the array.

**What I have tried:**
I have assign events with a loop, but I am getting in trouble with closure. The way I have it right now, all objects share the same event (the last one in the loop,) and when clicked, all give the same message.

`EventUtil` adds the event-handlers browser independently. It shouldn't contain any errors.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayWithObjects.length; i++) {
    EventUtil.addHandler(arrayWithObjects[i].getNode(), "contextmenu", function(event){
        event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('right click on '+arrayWithObjects[i].name);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: But why are you assigning over event when it's presumably getting passed in through your handler function?

Comment: You have a good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayWithObjects.length; i++) {
    (function(obj) {  // new function scope
        EventUtil.addHandler(obj.getNode(), "contextmenu", function(event) {
            event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('right click on ' + obj.name);
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    })(arrayWithObjects[i]); // pass in current object
}​
```

Comment: Curses. Foiled by AT&T again.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayWithObjects.length; i++) {
    (function(i){

    EventUtil.addHandler(arrayWithObjects[i].getNode(), "contextmenu", function(event){
        event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('right click on '+arrayWithObjects[i].name);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    })(i)
}
```

i is passed by value and made local for this defined-on-fly function creating a new closure every time.